# Python Import Error + DLL load failed + sys.path

Tags: python

in Python 2.7.10 Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit), if I write

```
sys.path.append('C:\\Anaconda\\sms-tools-master\\software\\models\\utilFunctions_C\\')
print sys.path
```

I get

C:\Anaconda\sms-tools-master\workspace\A1>python A1Part1.py
['C:\Anaconda\sms-tools-master\workspace\A1', 'C:\Anaconda\python27.zip',
'C:\Anaconda\DLLs', 'C:\Anaconda\lib', 'C:\Anaconda\lib\plat-win', 'C:\A
naconda\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\Anaconda', 'C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages', 'C:\
Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Sphinx-1.3.1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\Anaconda\lib\site-
packages\cryptography-0.9.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\Anaconda\lib\site-pack
ages\win32', 'C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\Anaconda\lib
\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-17.1.
1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\Anaconda\sms-tools-master\software\models\utilFunctions_C
\']

1. Is this absolute way of adding to sys.path correct? Is there a relative way?
2. In the next line of python code I wrote

   from utilFunctions_C import wavread

I instantly get

> ImportError: cannot import name wavread

if I run the code in cmd but if I run the code inside IDLE I get:

> ['C:\Anaconda\sms-tools-master\workspace\A1',
>   'C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib', 'C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip',
>   'C:\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\Python27\lib',
>   'C:\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk',
>   'C:\Python27', 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages',
>   'C:\Anaconda\sms-tools-master\software\models\utilFunctions_C\']
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Anaconda\sms-tools-master\workspace\A1\A1Part1.py", line 8, in
>   
>       from utilFunctions_C import wavread ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

So why there is a difference and how to tackle this issue? Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

I commented

```
from utilFunctions_C import wavread
```

and used

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
```

Now my code is okay. I found that

> utiLFunctions.wavread() is a wrapper that uses scipy.io.wavfile.read()
>   and scales the data to floating point between -1 and 1. If you open up
>   utilFunctions.py you will see that.
>
> You can use scipy.io.wavfile.read as well, as long you scale the data
>   correctly looking at the datatype in the wav file. Due to scaling, for
>   wav files that store samples as int16, you will see that
>   scipy.io.wavfile.read returns values will be 32767 times the values
>   returned by utilFunctions.wavread
>
> Lectures used the function to explain the process more explicitly.
>   Once you have got it, you can use the wrapper utilFunctions.wavread
>   for the rest of the course and in practical applications.

Scroll in 
https://class.coursera.org/audio-002/forum/search?[q=Cannot+import+name+wavread#15-state-query=wavread&15-state-page_num=1](https://class.coursera.org/audio-002/forum/search?q=Cannot%20import%20name%20wavread#15-state-query=wavread&15-state-page_num=1)

for more details.